# Do I need to use DPST for two loads?

Tags: switches

In the circuit shecmatic, the switch is an DPST switch, the input pins are in parallel.

I look for the advantages of DPST, it is mainly used on independant circuits. If the input is not independant, should I replace it with a SPST switch or a simple metal dome?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the DPDT switch in place, there is no value in changing it to SPST. Electrically, your circuits are equivalent. With no further context, that is your answer. To supplement:

- You can double the current capacity with the DPDT (or even DPST, in you case): the switch current rating is per pole. So if you have a DPDT/DPST switch rated 5A, wired the way you have it, your nominal capacity is now 10A.
- Even if you have enough capacity with using one pole alone, put the other pole in parallel with the first pole anyway. This will extend switch life as the current (and arcing) gets split across both poles not just one. This is much more valuable if you are switching a sparky load like a motor or transformer.
- The two pole switches a commonly used to break both phases of 230VAC systems. They are required for safety and compliance. Hopefully, this is not related to your application cause you aren't experienced to be working in that capacity and will likely cause harm.

Comment: Your comment is very good. I think those circuits are equivalent too.This is rubber keypad integrated with SMD tact switch and SMD LED. Usually, the metal dome was used in the product design, and the voltage shold be low.

Comment: @SYMak it's  not a comment ... it is an answer to your question

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)